# Questionario de setores em php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Aqui eu vejo quantas perguntas que tem em cada setor:

```sql
SELECT 
    a.area_id   AS ID_AREA,
    a.area_desc AS AREA_DESC,
    count(sb.sub_area_cod) AS TOTAL  
      FROM
        relacaoperg AS rp
         INNER JOIN area     AS a  ON rp.id_area = a.area_id 
         INNER JOIN sub_area AS sb ON rp.id_subgrupo =  sb.sub_area_cod
              WHERE 
                   id_area <> '1' GROUP BY AREA_DESC ASC;
```

Retorna da seguinte forma:

```
id  desc        total
2   FRENTE      18
3   FRIOS       36
4   ACOUGUE     35
5   MERCEARIA   27
6   HORTIFRUTI  31
7   PADARIA     33
```

Aqui vejo as respostas:

```sql
SELECT 
       a.area_id   AS ID_AREA,
       a.area_desc AS AREA_DESC,
       count(resp_area) AS TOTAL 
             FROM respostas as r 
               INNER JOIN area     AS a  ON r.resp_area     = a.area_id 
               INNER JOIN sub_area AS sb ON r.resp_subgrupo =  sb.sub_area_cod
                  WHERE 
                    resp_area <> '1' 
                    AND resp_questionario='3' 
                        GROUP BY resp_area;
```

Retorna da seguinte forma:

```
id  desc       total
3   FRIOS      32
5   MERCEARIA  27
```

Ou seja somente frios e mercearia que responderam.

No parte do select onde coloco: `resp_area <> '1'`  esse setor é a gerencia.

Preciso que o gerente só possa responder quando as respostas estiverem iguais as perguntas (mesma quantidade),ou seja,ele só pode responderem quando todos os setores já tiverem respondido.

Como poderia criar essa regra ?

Comment: mano não sei bem como ficaria a consulta, mas basicamente vc tem que somar o total das perguntas de todos os setores, tipo 18+36+35... e comparar com o total geral das perguntas, se for igual vc libera pra gerencia rs. Vc quer fzr isso no php ou no sql?

Comment: PHP.assim daria sim,mais eu queria também exibir para ele,qual setor não respondeu ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Salve o resultado das duas consultas em um array e utilize

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-assoc.php

para compara-las, dependendo do resultado você deixa ou não a gerencia responder